# Define values of a column as "text" while importing from .txt to .csv

Tags: python, csv, text, import

I have a text file that I need to convert into a csv file (so far no problem). However, one column has numbers and when I import the file the zeros in front of the numbers are dropped. I need the "0" to stay.

```
Req_num    P_ID   
15001      000989980
```

Therefore I need to be sure that the data type of the specific column is "text". Has anyone any ideas about it?

Comment: What does Python have to do with this?  The Python csv module won't convert strings to anything, unless you explicitly tell it to.  Is this actually an Excel question?

Answer (score 0):

### Python only solution

The file `test.txt`:

```
Req_num    P_ID   
15001      000989980
0123       0054321
```

The file `convert.py`:

```
import re

with open("test.txt", "r") as fin:
    with open("test.csv", "w") as fout:
        for line in fin.readlines():
            fout.write(", ".join(re.split("\s+", line.strip())) + "\n")
```

After running `python convert.py` you have in `test.csv`:

```
Req_num, P_ID
15001, 000989980
0123, 0054321
```

### Better solution with unix

File `convert.py`:

```
import re
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    print ", ".join(re.split("\s+", line.strip()))
```

Now you have to run `cat test.txt | python converty.py > test.csv` from your terminal.